# $cordovaInAppBrowser open url showing address bar weird

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

when I click on the url to open url using `$cordovaInAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', options)` it retired me to url when it opens the InAppBrowser it shows weird behavior.

this is my code

```
    var options = {
        location: 'yes',
        clearcache: 'yes',
        toolbar: 'no'
    };
    $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', options)
    .then(function (event) {
        // success
    })
    .catch(function (event) {
        // error
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve it using this code for Android as well as for ios

```
  self.viewLink = function (viewUrl) {

        var url = (viewUrl.match('http')) ? viewUrl : 'http://' + viewUrl;
        var options = {
            location: 'no',
            clearcache: 'yes',
            toolbar: 'yes',
            closebuttoncaption: 'Done'
        };
        $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', options)
        .then(function (event) {
            // success
        })
        .catch(function (event) {
            // error
        });
        return false;
    }
```

for me it work perfectly. hope so for some one it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below options.

iOS :

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(yourURL, '_blank', 'toolbar=no');
```

Android :

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open(yourURL, '_blank', 'location=no');
```

In your case *`cordova.InAppBrowser`* is  `$cordovaInAppBrowser`.